# How to recode in a tidy manner with better looking code

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am a medical researcher. I have a very large administrative database where the diagnoses are included in columns with headers dx1 - dx15 (dx = diagnosis). These columns contain numbers/letter codes which are in character form in R. I have written code to run through these dx columns, but would like to rewrite the code in the form of an array. I can do that easily in SAS, but am finding it difficult to do the same in R.

I am attaching the code that I use here:

`a <- as.character(c("4578","4551"))` # here I identify initially the codes for the diagnosis that I am interested in.

Then I create a new variable `cancer` in my dataframe `df` and use this code to identify patients with cancer. the new variable df$cancer will be either 0 or 1 depending upon diagnosis.

The code work, but as you can see, is not tidy and elegant at all.

```
df$cm_cancer <-  with(df, ifelse((dx3 %in% a | dx4 %in% a | dx5 %in% a |
                                    dx6 %in% a | dx7 %in% a | dx8 %in% a | dx9 %in% a |
                                    dx10 %in% a | dx11 %in% a | dx12 %in% a | dx13 %in% a |
                                    dx14 %in% a | dx15 %in% a), 1, 0))
```

With SAS, I can do the same with this elegant piece of code:

```
data df2;
    set df;
    cancer = 0;
    array dgn[15] dx1 - dx15;

    do i = 1 to 15;
        if dgn[i] in ("4578","4551") then
            cancer = 1;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

I refuse to believe that SAS has better answers for this than R; just agree that I am still a novice in the use of R.

Any help welcome; believe me, I have tried to google to find arrays in R, loops in R; anything that would help me to rewrite this code better.

Comment: Please provide some sample data with `dput()`.

Comment: `df$cm_cancer <- apply(df[paste0("dx", 3:15)], 1, function(x) any(x %in% a))` or `df$cm_cancer <- purrr::pmap_lgl(df[paste0("dx", 3:15)], ~any(.x %in% a))`

Comment: hard to test without data, but a `tidyverse` solution might be:
`df <- df %>%
  mutate(cm_cancer = ifelse(apply(df %in% a, 1, any), 1, 0))`

Comment: Or another `tidyverse` solution would be to pull into long format and then do the filter: `df_cancer <- df %>% gather(col, val, dx1:dx15) %>% filter(val %in% a)`

Comment: Or use `+(Reduce("|", lapply(df[paste0("dx", 3:15)], "%in%", a)))`